# pass arguments to Runtime.runtime().exec()

Tags: java, sql

I need to execute a sql file in JAVA, and I know the basic way to do this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sqlplus username@orcl/passwd @task.sql")
```

But now in task.sql, I defined a variable whose value must be passed from the java code. How can I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it is to generate separate sql file (task_exec.sql) from java using the original file (task.sql) as a template where in the task_exec.sql file all variables are set so there is no need to pass parameters externally. So all you have to do is to run the generated sql file.